# How can I create an array of sequential values from a value?

Tags: javascript

If I have the following:

```
var a = 5;
```

How can I make it so that this is converted into

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

I know it's a very simple question but I have never seen it done and cannot think of a simple way of doing it.

Comment: Is a good old loop fancy enough ?

Comment: `(new Array(a+1)).join('q').split('').map(function(_,i) { return i;});`

Comment: or `Array.apply(42,new Array(5)).map(function(_,i) { return i;});`

Comment: People here get reputation in the strangest way...

Comment: @dystroy - oooh, like the `42`, it is after all the answer to everything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use a loop and do:

```
var a = 5;
var arr = [];

for(var i=0; i<a; i++) {
   arr.push(i);    
}
```

As others have stated in their answers,

> Array direct assignment is even faster than Push

Having used `jsperf`, that appears to be incorrect for Chrome/Firefox. See below:

[image]

http://jsperf.com/js-array232

From this, I would use `push` as stated in my answer above.

Comment: @Alan - Not sure why you unaccepted my answer, the array assignment is indeed slower (See my proof attached).

Comment: @Vijay You only tested in IE8, IE11 is the same speed. Chrome and Firefox are **significantly faster**, so your argument is redundant.

Comment: @mattytommo: this is a piece of debate...just find this one :) 
http://jsperf.com/array-prototype-push-vs-direct-index-access/2

Comment: @Vijay Nope that's not applicable here, the key is that the assignments are **dynamic**, not a list of static statements.

Comment: @Daren - I clicked on your answer. Sorry I think I should have accepted it before.

Answer (score 3):

Array direct assignment is even faster than Push :

```
var arr=[],n=5;//N is 5 in your case
while(n--)
{
  arr[n]=n;
};
```

Performance proof for Internet Explorer: 
[image]

http://jsperf.com/js-array232/4

Comment: You're actually benchmarking against IE8? Dear me. Push is **significantly faster** in both Chrome and Firefox latest and it's actually a draw in IE11. Your performance argument was probably valid 5 years ago.

Comment: This is misleading. I guess people having upvoted that answer didn't even try the jsperf.

Answer (score 1):

The easy, obvious solution is just to use a for loop,

```
var a = 5, arr = [];
for (var i=0;i<a;arr.push(i++));
```

`arr` now contains your ascending array of length `a` (5).

Or use direct assignment,

```
var a = 5, arr = [];
while (a--) arr[a] = a;
```

for a slightly shorter, albeit slower, algorithm.